# Get first word of string inside array - from return REST

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, rest, split

I try get the `sessionid` before REST function, but in the case if I does not convert `toString();` show only numbers (`21 22 2e` ...).

**See this image:**

**1º**:
Obs.: Before using split.

```
 !!xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxx.rest.schema.xxxxResp {error: null, sessionID: qdaxxxxxxxxxxxxxj}
```

**My code:**

```
var Client = require('./lib/node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client();

var dataLogin = {
   data: { "userName":"xxxxxxxx","password":"xxxxxxxx","platform":"xxxxx" },
   headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
};

client.registerMethod("postMethod", "xxxxxxxxxxx/login", "POST");

client.methods.postMethod(dataLogin, function (data, response) {
   // parsed response body as js object
   // console.log(data); all return, image 1
   // raw response
if(Buffer.isBuffer(data)){
   data = data.toString('utf8'); // if i does not convert to string, return numbers, see image 1..
   console.log(data); //all inside image 2, and i want just value from sessionid

    var output = data;
    var res = output.split(" "); // using split
    res = res[4].split("}", 1);

  }
    console.log(res);  //image 3
});
```

I tested with `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` and it did not work, show just `'undefined'` for all. After convert `toString();`, And since I've turned the values ​​into string, I thought of using `split` to get only the value of `sessionid`.

And when I used `split`, all transform to `array` and the return is from `console.log(data)`, see image 2:

**2º:** 
Obs.: After use split and convert to `array` automatically.

[image]

And the return after use `split` is with the conditions inside my code:

**3º:**
And the return after use `split` is with the conditions inside my code:

```
  [ 'bkkRQxxxxxxxxxxxxx' ]
```

And I want just:

```
bkkRQxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I would like to know how to solve this after all these temptations, but if you have another way of getting the `sessionid`, I'd be happy to know.

Thanks advance!

Comment: You should really paste the text itself into your question instead of using screenshots. It makes it way easier to anonymize data, it's easier to read/use, and it uses less data for mobile users.

Comment: Instead of string manipulation. Use JSON.parse() on your data to return a JS object.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear, I use this too, but return undefined, maybe I do something wrong, you can post one example for it, please?

Comment: @qxz, okay, I'll edit, just a moment please.

Comment: What @qxz recommended.  And if you do screenshot, do a better job of covering your letters, I can still retrieve your personal information from what you've shared.

Comment: Thanks @Nol and other for informing.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear, if I use JSON.parse, The return are those numbers that: `<Buffer 21 21 62 72 2e 63 6f 6d 2e 63 65 6e 74 63...... > ` I Use JSON.parse(data) Instead of using `Buffer.isBuffer(data)`

Comment: Right, its a buffer that needs to be converted to a string first. It's strange that "!!xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxx.rest.schema.CtLoginResp" is actually in the string. Doesn't seem like a proper REST-ful API. If that string is constant, you can string.replace() it before passing it to JSON.parse()

Comment: @RayfenWindspear, I'll try, one moment please. And if I try and works, paste it with answer and I'll mark.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to figure out that the JSON was bad. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After converting the `Buffer` to a string, remove anything attached to the front with using `data.substr(data.indexOf('{'))`, then `JSON.parse()` the rest. Then you can just use the object to get the `sessionID`.

```
if(Buffer.isBuffer(data)){
    data = data.toString('utf8');
    data = data.substr(data.indexOf('{'));
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(obj.sessionID);
}
```

EDIT:
The issue you are having with `JSON.parse()` is because what is being returned is not actually JSON. The JSON spec requires the properties to be quoted ("). [See this article](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-parse-unquoted-JSON-with-JavaScript)

If the string looked like this, it would work: {"error": null, "sessionID": qdaxxxxxxxxxxxxxj}

Because the json is not really json, you can use a regular expression to get the info you want. This should get it for you.

```
re = /(sessionID: )([^,}]*)/g;
match = re.exec(data);
console.log(match[2]);
```

EDIT 2: After fully reading the article that I linked above (oops haha), this is a more preferable way to deal with unquoted JSON.

```
var crappyJSON = '{ somePropertyWithoutQuotes: "theValue!"  }';
var fixedJSON = crappyJSON.replace(/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(['"])?:/g, '"$2": ');
var aNiceObject = JSON.parse(fixedJSON);
```

Comment: I try it but the error is: `Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1 undefined:1
{error: null, sessionID: OHUr4XUC3BuVOrfV80Rs3Nk6} `
 ^

Comment: Print out the string before you JSON.parse() it. There is probably still something in the way. Basically you want to remove the first part until you are left with just {error: null, sessionID: xxxxxxxxx}

Comment: I try with obj = JSON.stringify(data); and return all it: "{error: null, sessionID: xxxxxxxxx}". I'll try what you say now

Comment: and with JSON.parse return undefined

Comment: Edited to make sure it removes everything before the json by using substr instead of replace.

Comment: I try with your edit, but, With JSON.stringify return `{error: null, sessionID: LjnSqXRT0tDm7ATZ1WFCq8gV}` and with JSON.parse return: `undefined:1
{error: null, sessionID: U69fTclTvwhV-xVX8-pixjOA}`

Comment: I dont understand why it dont worry, your solution is fine for others problem inside other question, I sure. But, when I try, does not work :\

Comment: I do what you say and get all json. But when I try get obj.sessionID, the error is Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1.. haha

Comment: I'll add a fiddle.

Comment: OH, I see what the problem is. json spec requires the properties to be quoted. The supposedly REST-ful API you are using isn't actually returning proper json.

Comment: In the case with ajax I can get the sessionid with `success:function(output) {
    console.log(output.sessionID);`, but with rest I try but does not work

Comment: That's because the API doesn't properly implement REST. If that side is also your responsibility, fix it so that it does. If it's someone else, then you'll just have to work around it.

Comment: I've talked to the API developers and they implement REST, that's why I'm doing it this way

Comment: Maybe the problem can do the `var Client = require('./lib/node-rest-client').Client;`. I dont know

Comment: I'll write you a regular expression that will do what you want.

Comment: thank you very much! You helped me a lot and were very attentive, thank you! After 4h I will +1

Comment: Rayfen, I see your edit now and thank u a lot for the help.